# Can a data attribute be set with css? if so then how?

Tags: html, css, attributes

I have the following html fragment with a custom data attribute data-parm1:

```
<div id="my_div" data-parm1="string_A" ></div>
```

Can I set data-parm1 with css ?

Comment: No, CSS styles elements. It can't change HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS can't be used to add, manipulate or create nodes in the DOM (Document Object Model). Your best bet is to use JavaScript `document.getElementById("my_div").setAttribute("data-param1", "StringB");`
The above code sets data-param1 to StringB.